# Only white Screen in swift project

Tags: swift, xcode

I have written a small application that displays the states in a table, but whenever I start the ios simulator it is only white and nothing is displayed.
When I use other projects or even no table view everything works great.
I have also worked with other templates where everything works great. But even if I replace the storyboard and the code with the prefabricated it does not work and the screen remains white

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var mydata = Country.readFromBundle()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
    
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return mydata.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel!.text = mydata[row].name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = mydata[row].capital
            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: mydata[row].name)
            return cell
        }
    }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Country {
    var name : String
    var population: Int
    var area : Double
    var capital : String
    
    static func readFromBundle() -> [Country] {
        var data = [Country]()
        let fmt = NumberFormatter()
        fmt.numberStyle = .decimal
        fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(
        forResource: "bundesländer", ofType: "txt")
        {
            do{
                let txt = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
                let lines = txt.split() { $0 == "\n"}.map {String($0)}
                for line in lines{
                    let columns = line.split() { $0 == "\t"}.map {String($0)}
                    if columns.count == 4{
                        let name = columns[0]
                        let area = Double(truncating: fmt.number(from: columns[1]) ?? 0.0)
                        let pop = Int(columns[2]) ?? 0
                        let cap = columns[3]
                        data.append(Country(name: name, population: pop, area: area, capital: cap))
                    }
                }
            }catch _ {}
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is in `readFromBundle()`.

I tried copying your code to a new project but since I don't have access to the txt file I just hardcoded some values into `readFromBundle()` so it looks like so:

```
static func readFromBundle() -> [Country] {
    var data = [Country]()
        
    data.append(contentsOf: [
        .init(name: "Germany", population: 2000000, area: 10.0, capital: "Berlin"),
        .init(name: "Denmark", population: 1000000, area: 10.0, capital: "Copenhagen"),
        .init(name: "Great Britain", population: 2000000, area: 10.0, capital: "London")
    ])
    return data
}
```

And that works as you can see here:

[image: iPhone with table contents]

### Suggestions

- Try stepping through the code in `readFromBundle()` to verify that it *actually* returns data to you.
- Alternatively, print out the contents of `data` just before you return it from the function.